# Union member as garbage value

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    union a 
    {
        short int i;
        char ch[2];
    };

    union a u;

    u.ch[0]=3;
    u.ch[1]=2;

    printf("%d\n",u.ch[0]);
    printf("%d\n",u.ch[1]);
    printf("%d\n",u.i);
    //printf("%d %d %d",u.ch[0],u.ch[1],u.i);
    return 0;

}
```

The given code has the output as 3,2,515 , how is it 515 ?

Comment: Do you usually shout?

Comment: Why not `515`??? It is not possible to answer the question when it is completely unclear what you see as a problem here. Why shouldn't it be `515`, in your opinion?

Comment: On a little-endian machine (Intel), 515 looks good: 2 * 256 + 3 = 515.  On a big-endian machine (SPARC, Power, ...), you'd probably get 770 (3 * 256 + 2).  There are some caveats about all this; read the standard or a good C book to find the details.  Suffice to say, in practice, you'll usually get one of the two answers I suggested, but the C standard doesn't specify that you'll get either of them.

Comment: I don't think that the proposed duplicate is particular accurate as a duplicate.  The answers there address the size of the structure more than the interpretation of the contents which is what this is about.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: ah, right. But this basic C expression simply *must* have been a mental challenge before; [what is the closest?](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%5D+union)

Answer (score 3):

Your machine is little endian, so the MSB is `2` and the LSB is `3`.

```
2 * 256 + 3 = 515
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using a union both element are stored at the same address. So you write both `ch` chars with values 3 and 2.

I assume your computer has an Intel CPU computer whose architecture is little Endian hence data will be stored from `LSB` to `MSB`.

RAM representation:

```
your_adress    : 2
your_adress + 1: 3
```

So that would be:

```
your_adress: 0x0203
```

Now convert it to decimal and you get

```
2*256 + 3 = 515
```